# Past/after in the given context

Tags: time

It's **past** 2 in the morning, who could be calling now?

It's **after** 2 in the morning, who could be calling now?

Is it correct to say either?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, both are fine.  In some dialects the use of "past 2" might sound slightly *formal* ... but either way, which you use is entirely personal preference.